# Гибкая работа с буфером глубины в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Хотелось бы прояснить ряд вопросов, касающихся работы с буфером глубины в OpenGL.

Сначала – главное: как задать точность буфера глубины? Насколько влияет точность буфера глубины на производительность?

Второе. Существует некоторое количество сфер на сцене. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы вся геометрия сцены рисовалась исключительно внутри этих сфер (или не рисовалась), а всё остальное за их пределами откидывалось за ненадобностью и не шло на обработку. Возможно ли добиться такого эффекта путём манипуляций с буфером глубины OpenGL?

Иногда на сцене бывает очень мало объектов и проверку глубины требуется совершать не по всему экрану, а лишь ограничившись некоторой зоной, непосредственно, где находятся сами объекты. Например, это может пригодиться в сцене большого поля с редкими деревьями, которые видны лишь на ограниченной области экрана.  В остальных областях экрана точность буфера глубины можно значительно снизить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Грамотный пример работы с `z-buffer` можно найти в [**`Nvidia OpenGL SDK`.**](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/opengl/samples.html#simple_depth_float) Точность буфера глубины, в принципе, можно переключать даже в рантайме и это очевидным образом сказывается на зрительных артефактах. *Также там описана одна широко распространенная проблема с `z-buffer'ом`, которая заключается в проблеме понижения точности, если одна из отсекающих плоскостей попадает в 0.0 по глубине.* Если вы еще с этим не знакомы, то рекомендую посмотреть [математическое обоснование](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision) работы `z-buffer'a`.
2. Понятно, что между точностью `z-buffera` и используемой точностью есть разница по производительности и она такая же, как разница между вычислениями во `float` и `double` - т.е **ничтожная.** Тем более, что вычисления в `z-buffer` никогда не будут `bottleneck'ом` вашего приложения, как бы вы ни старались.
3. **Чисто теоретически** сделать буфер глубины с переменной точностью можно так - взять какой-нить тип `partitioning'а` для пространства *(например, `quad-tree`)*, распарсить в нем все объекты и в местах сгущения объектов повысить точность с `16bit -> 32bit`. Но даже если вам удалось бы реализовать свой буфер глубины с переменной точностью с аппаратной поддержкой, то *затраты на определение точности для каждой из таких точек переплюнули бы выигрыш в скорости из-за вычислений с `float'ами` меньшей точности.* Поэтому-то и нет аппаратной поддержки для таких вещей.
4. Ваша ситуация со сферой решается не с помощью буфера глубины, а с помощью любого из [**алгоритмов `clipping'a`.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics)) Правда, в большинстве случаев вместо сферы как примитива для клиппинга используется либо ее низкополигональная аппроксимация, либо простейший `frustum`. *Причина этого очевидна - просчитать точные пересечения сложных объектов со сферой может быть чуть ли не дольше, чем отрисовать их, **здесь нужно всегда держать баланс** между временем, затрачивающимся на проверку и теоретическим верхним пределом времени на прокидывание соответствующего объекта по пайплайну.*

---

#### Update

---

**Точно** отрисовать все объекты внутри некоторой сферы *(или за ее пределами)* - задача, неразрешимая в реалтайме, поскольку для объектов, которые имеют пересечения со сферой, *необходимо видоизменить их так, чтобы пересечения превратились в касания.* Это означает проверки на пересечения для очень большого числа треугольников и необходимость в реалтайме что-то менять в `VBO` и индексных буферах.

В простой ситуации *"отрисовать все внутри сферы"* проблема решается тем, что, можно, например, рисовать все объекты, расположенные внутри сферы или пересекающие ее. Т.е с графической точки зрения отрисованная сфера **просто перекроет** объекты, выходящие за ее пределы и это должно выглядеть вполне приемлемо. Проверить пересечение можно с помощью задания некоторого `bounding volume` для каждого объекта.

---

Более сложная проблема, где становятся очевидными недостатки аппроксимации - это, например, **не допустить выход объектов за сферу**, *с учетом того, что они могут перемещаться в пространстве.* Поскольку произвольный объект аппроксимируется некоторым `bounding volume` *(сферой или AABB, в большинстве случаев)*, то, в зависимости от выбора этих самых `bounding volume` у нас объект либо будет иногда вылезать за границы сферы, либо, наоборот, никогда до нее не доходить.

Эта же проблема преследует многие *(даже совсем современные)* игры, где фигуры людей, например, могут частично "влезать" друг в друга при движении. И в общем случае такие вещи решаются увеличением точности `bounding volume`, что, естественно, вызывает более сложные просчеты коллизий.

Есть, кстати говоря, и совсем плохие ситуации - например, когда основная геометрия создается внутри геометрического шейдера, и, соответственно, просчет коллизий тоже хорошо бы совершать на шейдерах. *Вот тут вот и начинается высший пилотаж.*

Comment: Если манипуляция с точностью буфера глубины не даёт никаких преимуществ, то не стоит тратить на это время. Вернёмся к вопросу о сферах. В моём случае сферы должны быть идеальной формы или близкой к этому. Может быть существует возможность запрета рисования (или наоборот) в некоторой области пространства, ограниченной сферой? Сомневаюсь, что в данной ситуации может пригодиться клиппинг. Как вариант – это не самый лучший подход.

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer Ответил вам апдейтом.

Comment: Вот почему появился вопрос о работе с буфером глубины – как альтернативном варианте решения некоторых задач. В целом предложенные пути решения проблемы ясны. Идеальных путей не бывает.  Посмотрю, что из этого можно получить на практике.